# Raphael inner glow?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am looking for a way to achieve only an inner glow or shadow on a raphael path. Unfortunately, you can only do radial gradients on an ellipse or a circle.

One idea may be to create a series of paths which are slightly smaller and fit inside the original path and then to give them different stroke colors, but I have no idea how I would approach that. Some function that takes the path and subtracts or adds values to the numbers depending on where they are... Anyway, if anyone has any ideas, or maybe another javascript library that does this, that would be great.

Comment: You should accept the answer, I think it is a great solution.

Comment: @Brian Its not amazing by any means, because the glow will either continue outside the original path, or will have dissipated (be more transparent) when it reaches the original path. But okay, I will accept.

Comment: @Watson, if the glow continues outside, then make its scale smaller or change glow function's offsetx/offsety/opacity. Are you telling me  that if you have 2 identical shapes one smaller and one bigger, you cannot position smaller within the bigger perfectly?

Comment: @A.S.Roma There are two quasi-issues with your solution, one of witch cannot be avoided; the glow dissipates as it gets further away from the path which it is emanating from. So yes, you can of course position the glow-shape within another shape, but it doesn't look the same as it would if the glow were emanating (only in one direction) from the original shape. The glow dissipates by the time it reaches the original shape. This is not really how inner-glow should look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here is how you can achieve that. It is pretty straightforward I think. I know it is hard to manually create a shadow path from your original. But there is a trick called `scale()` function. Steps to how you can get inner shadow or inner glow effect:

1. Create your path
2. Clone it into another path
3. Set the scale() of cloned path to be 0.9*original
4. Then hide the cloned path, but apply glow() function on it

**The code:**

```
var paper = Raphael("notepad", 500, 500);

var path = paper.path("M 50 200 L 120 100  200 190 80 250z");
var shadow = path.clone().scale(0.9).hide();


shadow.glow();
path.attr({stroke: "darkred"});
```

Look at the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jUTFm/40/), this is not perfect but with minor changes, yo can get what you want.

**Also as a side note:**

`glow()` function has attributes like `offsetx, offsety, opacity`... Changing those attributes will give you your preferred shadow/glow.

**UPDATED CODE** http://jsfiddle.net/jUTFm/41/

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it would be possible to use the first path as a bounding box, so that the glow of the shadow would not extend outside the original path?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by saying "Changing those attributes will give you your preferred shadow/glow"

Comment: Also play with scale() function too, adjust based on your path

Comment: Check this update: http://jsfiddle.net/jUTFm/41/. This looks better. This is what I mean by saying play/experiment with it a little, you will eventually get you result

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eaPSC/2/). You could try animating the width of the path and darkening the color gradually to give some kinda glowing effect.

check out the bottom part

```
  brain = paper.add(brain);

  brain.attr('stroke', '#ff0');

  brain.transform('s 0.5, 0.5 0 0');

  glow = brain.glow({
    color: '#ff0',
    width: 5
  });

  anim = Raphael.animation({
    "stroke-width": 15,
    opacity: 1
  }, 500);


  anim = anim.repeat(Infinity);
  glow.animate(anim);
```

Comment: But the thing is, I only want the glow on the inside of the path, the outside should remain unaffected. Also, I don't want to mess with the stroke, at least not of the original path.

Comment: its hard to advise without any seeing any visuals, what do you mean by an inside of the path, are you refrring to the area which is untraced by your shape , if so, maybe you could have a rectangle background and try to glow that,your path should mask the regions which are under and the hollow area could do the trick ??

Comment: other advise could be to use drop shadow plugin, but add a color see here https://github.com/dahoo/raphael.dropshadow.js